# Get custom css property with a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

This is my code :

```
<html>
    <body>
    <button class="myclass" data-card-id="1">Save</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My question is how whould look like a function that when user click on any of "myclass" buttons submit a variable with data-card-id of the specific card in a php file.**
Thank you ! :)

Comment: Start with http://learn.jquery.com and then http://api.jquery.com/ (since the question is tagged with jQuery) - specifically class-selector, click handler and $.ajax()

Comment: You can bind event listener on buttons `.myclass` and get the target element from event to get the `data-card`-id`. Make an ajax request and hit the server on some url.

Comment: So, couldn't you just use [`jQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JSFIDDLE** - http://jsfiddle.net/q5j8z/11/

see browser console for data display

```
// change the selector "ul li a" to your button
$('ul li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    $('.button').data('value', value);
    console.log($('.button').data('value'));
});

$('.button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

this is using Jquery:

```
$(".myclass").click(function(){
     $(this).attr( "data-card-id" );
});
```

Comment: You can also do `$(this).data('card-id')`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished through an additional selection feature. I believe "data-card-id" is an attribute of your html tag, so you have two choices.

Bind the click to the element using the selector or delegate it to the body of the document, I think you'll see how either way works here.

Option 1.  The advantage here is that when click events bubble up to the body this will check and execut appropriately, even if other buttons are added to the page after this code is executed. This is jquery's click delegation feature

```
$('body').on('click', 'button[data-card-id="1"]', function(){
   //perform your action
});
```

Option 2.  This binds the click event to the object itself.  This can be more straight forward and has its advantage in simplicity.

```
$('button[data-card-id="1"]').click(function(){
  // perform some action
});
```

And of course you have a plethora of other approoaches......

or

```
$('button').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr("data-card-id") == '1'){
    $(this).click(function(){ 
      //some action
    });
  }
});
```

There are other approaches, too. Let  me know if none of these seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SqR34/1/)**

The most simpler would be to use this code -- > 
just change this `card-id` to this `cardid`

**HTML**

```
 <button class="myclass" data-cardid="1">Save</button>
 <button class="myclass" data-cardid="2">Save</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".myclass").on('click',function(){
    var cid = $(this).data("cardid");   
    alert(cid);
});
});
```